# Outputing command line text to Javafx Text Area

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, textarea, outputstream

I am trying to set it so that command line output goes to a Javafx TextArea for my GUI using the following code to write append to the TextArea the command line output:

```
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class CustomOutputStream extends OutputStream {
    private static TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
    public CustomOutputStream(TextArea textArea) {
        this.textArea = textArea;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b){
        textArea.appendText(String.valueOf((char)b));

    }
}
```

and

```
 PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(new CustomOutputStream(textArea));
        System.setOut(printStream);
```

However this seems to cause the GUI to stop responding giving the following out of bounds error:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 3
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:373)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:426)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.get(ObservableListWrapper.java:89)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.get(VetoableListDecorator.java:306)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.updateCachedBounds(Parent.java:1704)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.recomputeBounds(Parent.java:1648)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.doComputeGeomBounds(Parent.java:1501)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.doComputeGeomBounds(Parent.java:115)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.computeGeomBoundsImpl(ParentHelper.java:84)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper.superComputeGeomBoundsImpl(RegionHelper.java:78)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper.superComputeGeomBounds(RegionHelper.java:62)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.doComputeGeomBounds(Region.java:3289)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region$1.doComputeGeomBounds(Region.java:168)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper.computeGeomBoundsImpl(RegionHelper.java:89)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.computeGeomBounds(NodeHelper.java:115)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3843)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3805)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3753)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.intersectsBounds(Node.java:5288)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node$1.intersectsBounds(Node.java:549)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.intersectsBounds(NodeHelper.java:262)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.doPickNodeLocal(Region.java:3158)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region$1.doPickNodeLocal(Region.java:184)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper.pickNodeLocalImpl(RegionHelper.java:104)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.pickNodeLocal(NodeHelper.java:128)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.pickNode(Node.java:5198)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.pickNode(Scene.java:4033)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.pick(Scene.java:2065)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3843)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1885)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2618)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:409)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:299)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:447)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:412)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:446)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

Comment: This `@Override
    public void write(int b){
        textArea.appendText(String.valueOf((char)b));

    }` does not look correct. I think `int b` should be some kind of `KeyEvent`.

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Answer (score 1):

Here is a runnable example of converting a TextArea to the console output. I dont see any major differences I would remove that `import javax.swing.*;` and see what imports it needs

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;


public class MainNoFXML extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        TextArea textArea = new TextArea();

        System.setOut(new PrintStream(new CustomOutputStream(textArea)));

        VBox vBox = new VBox(textArea);
        vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);


        stage  = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(vBox));
        stage.show();

        System.out.println("Test Console Print to TextArea");
    }

    public class CustomOutputStream extends OutputStream {
        private TextArea textArea;
        public CustomOutputStream(TextArea textArea) {
            this.textArea = textArea;
        }

        @Override
        public void write(int b){
            textArea.appendText(String.valueOf((char)b));

        }
    }

}
```